# How should I write integers to a text file, then use them later by line on in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some integers that I would like to put onto a `.txt` file. My method of doing so is as follows where `int1 = 4565`, `int2 = 3` and `int3 = 169`.

```
savedata = open("SaveData.txt","w")
savedata.write("{}\n{}\n{}".format(int1,int2,int3))
savedata.close()
exit()
```

The .txt file produced looks like:

```
4565
3
169
```

When reading the file, this is what I have:

```
LoadData = open("SaveData.txt","r+")
new1 = LoadData.readlines(1)
format1= ("".join(new1))
new_int1 = int(format1)
new2 = LoadData.readlines(2)
format2 = ("".join(new2))
new_int2= int(format2)
new3 = LoadData.readlines(3)
format3 = ("".join(new3))
new_int3= int(format3)
```

Sorry, I understand the above may be very inefficient and messy. What I tried to do above, is use `"".join()` to get rid of the `[\n]`. Since writing them onto the text file made them strings, I used `int(format3)` to turn them back into integers. However, this is the error I get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3\n169'
```

My question is, how do I get the `4565`, `3` and `169` as printed onto the text file to become `new_int1 = 4565`, `new_int2 = 3` and `new_int3 = 169`?

I tried to use `rstrip("\n")` before using `int(format3)` but I couldn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `.readlines(x)` the `x` argument means how many lines to read, not which line. That means `new2 = LoadData.readlines(2)` ends up reading lines 2 and 3. Just stick to one line at a time and it will work as you expect. By switching to `.readline()` you can also skip the unnecessary `.join()`s.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I initially tried to use .readline() but constantly included .readline(1) - thinking that it was relative to the line number. I understand the error now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would just write to something like a JSON file that can recognize integers. The structure of the JSON file is simplified given the three integer example you gave us. [JSON documentation](http://www.json.org/), [Python JSON documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
import json

int1 = 4565
int2 = 3
int3 = 169

line = []
for num in [int1, int2, int3]:
    line.append(num)

print(json.dumps(line))

json_fnw = open('numbers.json', 'w')
json.dump(line, json_fnw)
json_fnw.close
```

Then, later when you want to extract the values:

```
json_fnr = open('numbers.json', 'r')
json_data = json.load(json_fnr)
json_fnr.close

print(json_data)
```

An alternative method for a more complex data structure would be to create JSON like this:
{"integers": [4565, 3, 169]}

using this code:

```
main_dict = {}
line = []
for num in [int1, int2, int3]:
    line.append(num)
main_dict['integers'] = line

json_fnw = open('numbers.json', 'w')
json.dump(main_dict, json_fnw)
json_fnw.close
```

where the data would be extracted like this:

```
json_fnr = open('numbers.json', 'r')
json_data = json.load(json_fnr)
json_fnr.close

for num in json_data['integers']:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using tuple unpacking:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    int1, int2, int3 = (int(val) for val in f.read().split())
```

The default behavior for split is to split on any whitespace, including newline characters.

Or you could just iterate over the file object itself, instead stripping newlines.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    int1, int2, int3 = (int(l.strip()) for l in f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wondering, what does with open(file) as f: mean?

Comment: @Yac, the `with` statement is actually the preferred way to access files in Python. Files are resources that code should be careful about how it handles -- whenever we open a file, it's good form to close it, too. The `with` statement automatically closes the file when we leave the block (i.e. the indentation goes back to what it was before). The `with` statement can be used with objects called 'context managers,' one of which `file` is. You can learn more here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes good sense as I was closing using `.close()` . I will read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the whole file you should be getting

```
'4565\n3\n169'
```

The easiest way to format this into an array should be

```
values = map(int, filter(None, f.read().split('\n')))
```